# net share not working as expected?

Tags: windows, samba

I'm creating a SMB share on a windows machine using the net share command.
I write

```
net share MyCompany_server___0.0.1-SNAPSHOT___server=E:\JavaWorkspace\Product\src\generated\server
```

Then, this share is visible by other Windows machine in network shares of my machine, but not be accessed. Is there an option I forgot to set ?

**EDITED** due to comment

- Accessing the share using an OpenSUSE machine brings the "The folder contents could not be displayed." message.
- Accessing the share using the Windows machine sharing that folder succeeds without any issue
- Accessing the share using another Windows machine displays

> MyCompany_server___0.0.1-SNAPSHOT___server
>   is not accessible. Access refused

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: If you set the share name to something shorter e.g. "test", does it work then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're in a "workgroup" environment, but you don't mention the "server" computer's OS.

It sounds to me like you've got a permission problem on the underlying NTFS. Without knowing the "server's" version of Windows it's fairly difficult to tell you much more than that.

If the "server" is a Windows Server version and you do a "NET USE * \server\sharename /user:Administrator" from a client computer and specify the "server's" Administrator password when prompted (assuming that you're using an "Administrator" account on the "server") you may have luck.

If the "server" is a Windows client version, though, you've probably got option turned on to treat all remote connection attempts as "Guest" and the underlying NTFS permissions will prevent any access to the contents of the share.

More information will help us tell you what's going on.

BTW: That's a heck of a share name you've got there.